# Intersection of N files

Tags: bash, shell, intersection

I've got a little problem in `bash`.

I've got `N` files  containing filenames, and I would like to find the list of filenames which are contained in all the file (the intersection of the files).

When there is 2 files, I found this solution: `sort file1 file2 | uniq -d`, and this is actually doing what I want.

But how to generalize it to `N` files in the same folder ?

---

```
File1

    1 
    2 
    3 
    4

File2

    1 
    4

File3

    2 
    3 
    4

Output expected:

    4
```

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards.

Comment: use a wildcard? `sort file*|...`?

Comment: Not working. It looks more like the 'distinct union', not the intersection... :/

Comment: `uniq -d -c`, then grep for the number of files you included? since you're piping the files, uniq cannot know where the data came from, or how many files were used to produce that input. it can only count dupes.

Comment: @MarcB, you indeed crack my problem :D thank you very much :)
Can you write a correct answer than I can accept as the solution of the problem (for futur people facing the same kind of problem ?)

Comment: Can you have input files with duplicates? File1 with 3 times x, other files without?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I`m not Marc B, but still, here`s the implementation of his idea:

```
intersect() {
    sort "$@" | uniq -cd | grep "^[^0-9]*$# "
}

# usage example
intersect file1 file2 file3
```

[EDIT:] To overcome the problem of duplicate lines within the same file, I`d do something like this:

```
intersect() {
    for file in "$@"; do
        sort -u "$file"
    done | sort | uniq -cd | grep "^[^0-9]*$# "
}
```